# What commands exist just for fun?

Tags: command-line

There's lot of stuff we can do at a terminal, many of them very useful.

But, what commands are there that exist only to amuse the user?

Comment: This is extraordinarily broad, and I believe does not fit with the types of Q/A posts we are looking for on this site (per the Help Center and Meta discussions)

Comment: @ThomasW. It is very broad, but the answer is very good, perhaps Freddy could try to reword the question slightly to be a better fit ? I believe this could have some value here.

Comment: The point remains: a question asking for a list of things without limit is not a good fit for Stack Exchange.

Comment: @muru There are questions here asking for list of things. http://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available/38006#38006

Comment: @Freddy care to read the first paragraph on that?

Comment: @muru Oh I am really sorry i did not read that! :(

Comment: From time to time we make exceptions to the **too broad** rule. I think this case might qualify.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. **sl**

   Very often we mistype `ls` as `sl`.

   what if you get something like this:

[image]

install sl:

```
sudo apt-get install sl
```

---

2. **Fortune**

   Fortune ----> prints random stuff

[image]

install fortune:

```
sudo apt-get install fortune
```

---

3. **Cowsay(part 1)**

   want cow on terminal?

[image]

install cowsay

```
sudo apt-get install cowsay
```

**cowsay + fortune**

[image]

---

4. **cowsay(part 2)**

   you will see something like this:

[image]

install xcowsay

```
sudo apt-get install xcowsay
```

---

5. **cmatrix**

[image]

install cmatrix

```
sudo apt-get install cmatrix
```

---

6. **bb**(one of mine favourite)

[image]

press 8. turn up volume to max(wear headphone)

it will show you something like this:

[image]

And then it will play music!

install bb

```
sudo apt-get install bb
```

---

Comment: Can you explain a bit what `bb` does?

Comment: @ByteCommander  I have edited answer.